# position_dodge when using separate datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am attempting to produce a graph that shows two groups of error bars, but the different error bars represent different estimates of central tendency/variability (e.g., mean with sd and median with quantiles). I'm trying to use position_dodge, but it's not working, and I suspect this is because I'm feeding it values from a different dataset. Here's a reproducible example:

```
    #### simulate dosages
dose = factor(rep(c("small", "medium", "large"), times=10))
dose = relevel(dose, "small")

    #### simulate fevers, based on dosage (but highly skewed)
fever = rnorm(length(dose), 100, 1)
betas = matrix(c(0, -3, -6), nrow=1)
fever = fever + as.numeric(betas%*%t(model.matrix(fever~dose)))

    #### put into data frame
d = data.frame(dose=dose, fever=fever)

    #### compute means and standard errors
means = d %>% group_by(dose) %>% summarise(mean=mean(fever), lower=mean - sd(fever), upper = mean + sd(fever))
medians = d %>% group_by(dose) %>% summarise(median=median(fever), lower=quantile(fever, .25), upper = quantile(fever, .75))

    #### put all into a ggplot
ggplot(d, aes(x=dose, y=fever)) +
    geom_jitter(alpha=.2, width=.2) +
    geom_point(data=means, aes(x=dose, y=mean)) +
    geom_point(data=medians, aes(x=dose, y=median), col="red") +
    geom_errorbar(data=means, aes(y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.2, position=position_dodge(width=.2)) + 
    geom_errorbar(data= medians, aes(y=median, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.2, position=position_dodge(width=.2), col="red")
```

Which gives the results of the following image:

[image]

Notice dodging isn't working.

Let's assume I can't just use stat_summary (I can't...I'm actually comparing means with some robust estimates from another package). Is there any way to offset the error bars/dots so they can be better seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your dataframes for both statistics so you can map the kind of statistic on `group`:

```
means <- df %>% 
  group_by(dose) %>% 
  summarise(Statistic = "Mean", Value = mean(fever), lower=mean(fever) - sd(fever), upper = mean(fever) + sd(fever)) 

medians <- df %>% 
  group_by(dose) %>% 
  summarise(Statistic = "Median", Value = median(fever), lower=quantile(fever, 0.25), upper = quantile(fever, 0.75)) 

df2 <- bind_rows(means, medians)

#### put all into a ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = fever)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = .2, width = .2) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = dose, y = Value, color = Statistic)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = df2, aes(y = Value, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, 
                group = Statistic, color = Statistic), 
                width=.2, position = position_dodge(width = .2))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. Simple and concise. Thanks!